# c3.js: axis-y label overlapped

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

Because of my special requirement, I customized to change the label of y axis upon the y axis, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45141524/c3-js-change-label-position-of-line-chart-y-axis-to-center-up-of-y-axis).

The answerer solved my problem, but later I got another one. I tried several methods but still without luck.

***Question:*** If the label was too long, it'll be overlapped, see the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WzXVForyGJP01WJlAXj5?p=preview) demo.

```
var chart = c3.generate({ 
  padding: {
    top: 10
  },
  data: {
      columns: [
          ['data', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]
      ]
  },
  axis: {
      y: {
          label: {
              text: 'Y Axis Label Something Else Blah! Blah! Blah!',
              position: 'inner-top'
          } 
      }
  }
});
d3.select(".c3-axis-y-label").attr("transform", "translate(26,-16)");
```

===========================================================================

```js
// Code goes here
(function(){
  
  var chart = c3.generate({ 
      padding: {
        top: 10
      },
      data: {
          columns: [
              ['data', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]
          ]
      },
      axis: {
          y: {
              label: {
                  text: 'Y Axis Label Something Else Blah! Blah! Blah!',
                  position: 'inner-top'
              } 
          }
      }
  });
  
  d3.select(".c3-axis-y-label").attr("transform", "translate(26,-16)");
  
})();
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

#chart {
  margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/c3@0.4.14/c3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@3.5.6/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/c3@0.4.14/c3.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the `clip-path` in that axis:

```
d3.select(".c3-axis-y").attr("clip-path", null)
```

Then, set the `text-anchor` to `start`:

```
d3.select(".c3-axis-y-label")
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,-16)");
```

Here is your code with the changes:

```js
// Code goes here
(function(){
  
  var chart = c3.generate({ 
      padding: {
        top: 10
      },
      data: {
          columns: [
              ['data', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]
          ]
      },
      axis: {
          y: {
              label: {
                  text: 'Y Axis Label Something Else Blah! Blah! Blah!',
                  position: 'inner-top'
              } 
          }
      }
  });
  
  d3.select(".c3-axis-y").attr("clip-path", null)
  
  d3.select(".c3-axis-y-label")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,-16)");
  
})();
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

#chart {
  margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/c3@0.4.14/c3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@3.5.6/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/c3@0.4.14/c3.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, @Gerardo Furtado, you helped me a lot. Really appreciate your creative ideas. 

However, for this one, I have a concern, the `clip-path` was automated added by `c3`, won't it have any side effects if we remove it directly? 

And the label is not upon the middle of axis-y anymore. Do you have any further ideas? 

Kindly waiting for your reply.

Comment: I have no idea of the purpose of that clip-path, I'm not a C3 user, I'm a D3 coder. Therefore, you'll have to check if this has any side effect. Regarding the position of the label, if you have a huge label that you want to put in the middle of the axis, you'll have to move the axis to the right, setting the left padding.

Comment: your answer really inspired me, it's very helpful.